# Inserting text into new Word 2010 file using Deplhi XE2

Tags: delphi, ms-word, delphi-xe2

I've written a program in Deplhi XE2 to create a new Word document (using Word 2010 and TWordApplication), insert text, and save it as both a .doc file and a .pdf file.
The two Word components are on the form.
Everything works except for the text insertion. When I open the documents after the fact they are both empty.

```
procedure TForm1.btnGenerateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sNewText: WideString;
begin
  sNewText := 'Hello, World!' + #13;
  { Create the Word document, set text and close it. }
  WordApplication1.Visible := False;

  WordApplication1.NewDocument;
  WordApplication1.Selection.EndOf(wdStory, wdMove);
  WordApplication1.Selection.InsertAfter(sNewText);
  WordApplication1.Selection.EndOf(wdStory, wdMove);

  if FileExists('d:\temp\MyNewDocDup.doc')
  then DeleteFile('d:\temp\MyNewDocDup.doc')
  else ;
  WordDocument1.SaveAs('d:\temp\MyNewDocDup.doc');

  if FileExists('d:\temp\MyNewDocDup.pdf')
  then DeleteFile('d:\temp\MyNewDocDup.pdf')
  else ;
  WordDocument1.SaveAs('d:\temp\MyNewDocDup.pdf', 17);

  WordDocument1.Close;
  WordApplication1.Disconnect;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the problem is likely that the document object `WordDocument1` is not the document in which the text is added. The text is added fine, just to a different document. Here is a simple example that demonstrates how to do it:

```
var
  app: TWordApplication;
  doc: WordDocument;
....
app := TWordApplication.Create(nil);
try
  app.Visible := False;
  doc := app.Documents.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  app.Selection.EndOf(wdStory, wdMove);
  app.Selection.InsertAfter('Hello, World!');
  app.Selection.EndOf(wdStory, wdMove);
  doc.SaveAs('C:\desktop\MyNewDocDup.doc', EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  doc.SaveAs('C:\desktop\MyNewDocDup.pdf', 17, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  doc.Close(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  app.Quit;
finally
  app.Free;
end;
```

In real code you'd use the named file format constants rather than the magic number 17.

Note that [`NewDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.newdocument%28v=office.15%29.aspx) does not create a new document. Instead you need to use `Documents.Add` to make a new document. Note also the pain of early binding – all those `EmptyParam` arguments are no fun at all. If you are building a large amount of code on top of Office it pays to wrap up such messy details.

As for the documentation to the Office automation API, that can be found on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861527.aspx

Comment: This code did the trick after adjusting for an apparently known issue (http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=173683). I kept getting "cannot save to the same name as the open doc" error. Made some adjustments to the Word Save options and it worked. Then my .pdf save line kept getting "Command failed" and it took me an hour before I saw that the colon after the drive in the path was actually a semi-colon. You are always your own worst proof-reader.

Comment: If this answers your question, perhaps you might care to accept. I offer this advice because I can see you are new.

Comment: Be happy to accept if I knew how to do that. I find this site protocol a bit confusing in this regard. Ans yes, new to the forum but 50+ years in DP. BTW, I have the type constants (printed, in fact) but '17' was easy for the test pgm. -- Thanks.